# What is the reason to use the attribute 'script language="javascript"' when inserting a JavaScript file?

Tags: javascript, html

I know that doing

```
<script language="javascript" src="script.js">
```

or

```
<script src="script.js">
```

are the same. I just want to understand if there are cases when we **must**  add **language="javascript"**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The attribute is required if you are writing HTML 3.2 (which you should not be, this is the 21st century).

You may add it if you are writing HTML 4.x or XHTML 1.x (which you should not be, this is 2017).

It is obsolete (and should be omitted) if you are writing HTML 5.

Comment: Also, it was used when vbscript was a thing on IE. Now-a-days, we only use Javascript and the use of the attribute is nearly unnecessary. You could still use it to other languages. PHP<7 used `<script language="php">...</script>` as opening and closing tags.

Answer (score 1):

From [Obsolete but conforming features](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/obsolete.html#obsolete-but-conforming-features),

> Authors should not specify a [`language`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/obsolete.html#attr-script-language) attribute on a
>   [`script`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#the-script-element) element.
>
> If the attribute is present, its value must be an [ASCII
>   case-insensitive](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#ascii-case-insensitive) match for the string "`JavaScript`" and either
>   the [`type`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#attr-script-type) attribute must be omitted or its value must be an
>   [ASCII case-insensitive](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#ascii-case-insensitive) match for the string "`text/javascript`".
>
> The attribute should be entirely omitted instead (with the value
>   "`JavaScript`", it has no effect), or replaced with use of the
>   [`type`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#attr-script-type) attribute.

So what's important is the [`type`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#attr-script-type). You don't need to make it explicit, though.

> The `type` attribute gives the language of the script or format of the
>   data. If the attribute is present, its value must be a [valid MIME
>   type](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#valid-mime-type). The `charset` parameter must not be specified.
>
> The default, which is used if the attribute is absent, is "`text/javascript`".

Answer (score 0):

According to [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script) (a great reference for HTML, JS, DOM, etc.)

> **language**
>   Like the type attribute, this attribute identifies the scripting language in use. Unlike the type attribute, however, this attribute’s possible values were never standardized. The type attribute should be used instead.

Therefore, the `language` attribute should probably not be used.

The `type` attribute in the same docs say:

> **type**
>   This attribute identifies the scripting language of code embedded within a script element or referenced via the element’s src attribute. This is specified as a MIME type; examples of supported MIME types include text/javascript, text/ecmascript, application/javascript, and application/ecmascript. If this attribute is absent, the script is treated as JavaScript.

Therefore, the minimal version is acceptable:

```
<script src="script.js">
```

And the most correct explicit version is:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js">
```